# define anagram Python

Tags: sorting

For example:
cat - kitten  The words aren't anagrams;
cat - act  The words are anagrams;
cat - cat should be  The same words.
What should l do in this code to include The same words:

```
s1 = input("Enter first word:")
s2 = input("Enter second word:")
a = sorted(s for s in s1.lower() if s.isalpha())
b = sorted(s for s in s2.lower() if s.isalpha())
if sorted(a) == sorted(b):
    print("The words are anagrams.")
else:
    print("The words aren't anagrams.")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do a check after gathering the input.

````
    s1 = input("Enter first word:").lower().lower()
    s2 = input("Enter second word:")
    if s1 != s2:
        a = sorted(s for s in s1 if s.isalpha())
        b = sorted(s for s in s2 if s.isalpha())
        if sorted(a) == sorted(b):
            print("The words are anagrams.")
        else:
            print("The words aren't anagrams.")
    else:
        print("The words are anagrams.")
    ```
````

Comment: There's no need to sort a sorted list again.

Comment: the simple point  if s1 != s2:   is enough for right solving